# How can I add one appspot application as a path to another domain that already points to an appspot project?

Tags: google-app-engine

We have an appspot application deployed to http://example.com.  The appspot id, for example, is `app1`.  The other application is at `app2`.

The domain app1 is mapped to is example.com.  We want to map `app2` to example.com/app2.

Is it possible to force the first application to load the second application on the /app2 path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, be careful not to violate the [App Engine TOS](http://code.google.com/appengine/terms.html):

> 4.4. You may not develop multiple Applications to simulate or act as a
>   single Application or otherwise access
>   the Service in a manner intended to
>   avoid incurring fees.

With that in mind, what you can do easily is run the second app on a subdomain, e.g. `app2.example.com`. Using a subdirectory is trickier. You can set up a redirect handler in app1 that passes customers from the subdirectory over to the subdomain. If you want to actually run the app from the subdirectory, you would need your own proxy server in front to rewrite the requests server side.